# Pure javascript div resize event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need you because I need to detect if a div is resizing and I just found some solution using JQuery and window.resize.

The thing is that I don't want to use any library, and the window is not resizing. The div is resizing because a menu pop up. I could do that with a dispatch event on the menu, but I want my widget to work itself.

JS FIDDLE :
http://jsfiddle.net/b7mNU/3/

I want to get the onresize of the red rectangle without using the event on the menu (yellow div).
Something like :

```
child.addEventListener('resize', function(){ /* do something */ }, false);
```

Comment: Please provide some code and/or a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: any change on this since 2012?

Answer (score 1):

These is no such event for `<div>` elements. You could however use an interval function to watch the state of it's `style.width` and `style.height`. If that changes fire a callback.

Comment: I could use that, but it's heavy.. :/

Comment: Have you tried? You can't just assume something is heavy. Maybe if you watch a really large quantity of elements. Just checking some properties isn't heavy at all.

Comment: The thing is that I have already a lot of timer for other modules which really need it. And I had some problem with IOS because of the timers (setInterval).. I know that it's a pain to find a proper solution for that.

Comment: For now, I will use a dispatch event in the menu module, but if someone have some other ideas, I'll take it. (sorry, I maned, I still have some issues with the timers)

Answer (score -1):

You can change your text or Content or Attribute or Style Sheet depend on Screen size:
HTML:
You can follow :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

```
<p class="change">Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)</p>
<p class="change">Frequently Asked Questions </p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
const changeText = document.querySelector('.change');
function resize() {
  if((window.innerWidth<500)&&(changeText.textContent="Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)")){
    changeText.textContent="FAQ";
  } else {
    changeText.textContent="Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)";
  }
}
window.onresize = resize;
</script>
```

Comment: OP mentioned he specifically needs to monitor an element resizing; not the window.